# regex to find every two commas, to separate rows from a column using dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, separator

**I have strings like this one:**

```
71,72,80,81,102,100
```

**Which I want to separate every 2 "numbers", so:**

```
71,72
80,81
102,100
```

**I wrote this regex:**

```
(([0-9]{1,4}),([0-9]{1,4}))
```

Which higlights the groups I need, except the comma in between ","

In my code I am using `dplyr`

Example:

```
df_example <- tibble(Lotes= "LOT1,LOT2,LOT3",NoModuloPlastico = "71,72,80,81,102,100")

df_result_example <- df_example %>%
separate_rows(c(Lotes),sep=",") %>%
separate_rows(c(NoModuloPlastico),sep="(([0-9]{1,3}),([0-9]{1,3}))")
```

**Which means** what I really need is to highlight every 2 commas with regex, but I can't find how.

I couldn't adapt these links to my needs:

https://bedigit.com/blog/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern/

https://blog.codinghorror.com/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions/

**What I get:**

| Lotes | NoModuloPlastico |
| --- | --- |
| LOT1 | "" |
| LOT1 | "," |
| LOT1 | "," |
| LOT1 | "" |
| LOT2 | "" |
| LOT2 | "," |
| LOT2 | "," |
| LOT2 | "" |
| LOT3 | "" |
| LOT3 | "," |
| LOT3 | "," |
| LOT3 | "" |

**What I want:**

| Lotes | NoModuloPlastico |
| --- | --- |
| LOT1 | 71,72 |
| LOT2 | 80,81 |
| LOT3 | 102,100 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a bit shortened [Onyambu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050366/3832970):

```r
df_example %>% 
  mutate(Lotes = strsplit(Lotes, ','),
    NoModuloPlastico = NoModuloPlastico %>% 
      strsplit('[^,]*,[^,]*\\K,', perl=TRUE)) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Lotes NoModuloPlastico
  <chr> <chr>           
1 LOT1  71,72           
2 LOT2  80,81           
3 LOT3  102,100
```

**NOTES**:

- `strsplit(Lotes, ',')` splits `Lotes` column with a comma
- `strsplit('[^,]*,[^,]*\\K,', perl=TRUE)` splits the `NoModuloPlastico` column with every other comma. `[^,]*,[^,]*` matches zero or more non-comma chars, a comma and zero or more non-comma chars, `\K` omits these chars matched, and then `,` matches a comma that is used to split the string with.

Comment: This is fantastic dear Wiktor :)

Answer (score 9):

You could do:

```
df_example %>%
  mutate(Lotes = str_split(Lotes, ','),
         NoModuloPlastico = NoModuloPlastico %>%
           str_replace_all('([^,]+,[^,]+),', '\\1:') %>%
           str_split(':')) %>%
  unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Lotes NoModuloPlastico
  <chr> <chr>           
1 LOT1  71,72           
2 LOT2  80,81           
3 LOT3  102,100
```

Comment: Inspirational as always :) upvoted already though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_example %>%
  mutate(NoModuloPlastico = paste0(regmatches(NoModuloPlastico, gregexpr("\\d+,\\d+", NoModuloPlastico))[[1]],
                                   collapse = " "), 
         Lotes = gsub(",", " ", Lotes)) %>%
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = "\\s+")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Lotes NoModuloPlastico
  <chr> <chr>           
1 LOT1  71,72           
2 LOT2  80,81           
3 LOT3  102,100
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this generalizes your problem, if it doesn't, try to find a variation of this method.

```
# Your tibble
df_example  = dplyr::tibble(Lotes= "LOT1,LOT2,LOT3",NoModuloPlastico = "71,72,80,81,102,100")

# with strsplit separate the strings by "," and turn them into a matrix
A = matrix(strsplit(df_example$Lotes, split = ",")[[1]],ncol=1,)
B = matrix(strsplit(df_example$NoModuloPlastico, split = ",")[[1]], ncol = 2)

# cbind the two matrices, turn that into a dataframe and give names to the columns
C = as.data.frame(cbind(A,B))
colnames(C) = c("Lotes", "Modulo1", "Modulo2")

# Create your new column with paste0() function
C$NoModuloPlastico = paste0(C$Modulo1, ",",C$Modulo2)

# This is extra but only for following your variable name create that with the two columns.
df_result_example = data.frame(C$Lotes, C$NoModuloPlastico)
```

This solves your example in base R.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace every second occurrence of comma to semi-colon (or any other separator), change the comma values in `NoModuloPlastico` to semi-colon as well and use `separate_rows`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_example %>%
  mutate(NoModuloPlastico = gsub('(,.*?),', '\\1;', NoModuloPlastico), 
         Lotes = gsub(',', ';', Lotes, fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  separate_rows(Lotes, NoModuloPlastico, sep = ';')

#  Lotes NoModuloPlastico
#  <chr> <chr>           
#1 LOT1  71,72           
#2 LOT2  80,81           
#3 LOT3  102,100
```